# How to get osm_id of the nominatim address component?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

This is the example request to nominatim:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=milan,%20italy&format=json&addressdetails=1&accept-language=en

This is the address:

```
"address":{"city":"Milan","county":"Milan","state":"Lombardy","country":"Italy","country_code":"it"}
```

All of address components have osm_id's and I want to know them, like this:

```
 "address":{"city":["Milan", <milanId>],"county":["Milan",  <milanId>],"state":["Lombardy", <lombardyId>],"country":["Italy", <italyId>]}
```

How can I get them?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible with the current API. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get identifiers of the address components. It should be possible. If it is not, it should be written with the reason in documentation.

Comment: Why should the documentation mention features it doesn't provide? This would be silly.

Comment: scai, because this function is expected.

Comment: Not really. Nominatim is a geocoder. It is supposed to convert an address into coordinates and convert coordinates into an address. Other features are optional. If you want to find out more about a specific OSM element then Nominatim is the wrong tool for this task.

Comment: scai,  it is very strange because I think adding id to address component is easy. Why do top level components in query results have ids? If ids are needed they should be everywhere and nowhere if they aren't. But they are needed.

Comment: @kz_sergey Using osm ids is not the right thing for most use cases, because they are not stable. They can basically change any time.

Comment: @Thomas Skowron  and what id is stable?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case you can use the `is_in` query of [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). See the [example at overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/lC9) for the coordinates of Milan:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
is_in(45.4667971,9.1904984);
out;
```